# Firefox no longer resends POST data on refresh

Tags: firefox, browser, redirection, forms

When you've just sent a form then refresh, if you haven't used the [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, Firefox will ask you if you want to resend your form data. If you click Resend, the page would normally reload and the form processing code would do its thing again.

In production, usually, I redirect so this doesn't happen. While developing, though, it can be very useful to be able to refresh and see my debug dumps with the same post data as my code changes, without having to fill the form again or use a tool such as [Postman](https://www.postman.com/). Just fill the form, `die()` before the redirect, and test away.

In the last few months, it seems something changed, and Firefox now only pretends to resend the data on a refresh. It still asks me, but even when the following code is the very first thing executed, `$_POST` is an empty array.

```php
<?php
  echo '<pre>';
  var_dump($_POST);
  echo '</pre>';
  die();
?>
```

Meanwhile, following the same steps on Chrome *does* give me back my $_POST array like it used to.

I was away from work for several months, so I'm not sure what changed, but since using Firefox in Safe Mode (without add-ons) yields the same result, I'm almost sure the issue is there. I use Firefox 75 on Mac.

Is there a hidden preference that changes the behaviour of resending POST data on refresh? Can I fix this?

Comment: Now it doesn't ask, just sends a GET request to the same URL.  The old behaviour was much more useful.

Comment: Agreed. It would be nice if there were a way to change it back.

Comment: Seems it is dependent on something that JavaScript can control, but not clear what.  Simple test setup and expected prompt about resubmitting appears.  But something implemented in WordPress admin and POST request is resubmitted as GET without prompt - console log shows clearly it was not PRG.  With JavaScript disabled, in both cases, a prompt appears before the POST request is repeated.

Comment: It seems use of [`History.replaceState`](https://dtbaker.net/files/prevent-post-resubmit.php) can prevent POST request being repeated.

Comment: Maybe that's what WordPress does, somewhere, as part of its security?

Comment: Probably more because it was less effort than properly implementing [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), and they stumbled upon an easy solution that would work in most modern browsers (with JavaScript enabled).  Follow the chain of links from my previous comment for more info.  It's not related to security (you can't implement security client-side), but user experience (when the user refreshes the page).  Does this relate to or shed any light on your situation (or have you now moved on or otherwise resolved the issue)?

Comment: I'm sorry... I actually changed jobs, and I haven't done WordPress or PHP in months. I won't really be able to investigate this further. :(

Answer (score 3):

Try `about:config` and setting `dom.confirm_repost.testing.always_accept` = `true`
Helped me in Firefox 84

Comment: Can't confirm since I no longer work with that stack but that sounds promising! I'll accept the answer is someone else can confirm that it fixes the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Great, it worked for me! Do you know if an option exists to allow this only on some URLs? For instance, just for localhost